# PHP Date Format: ISO8601 vs ISO8601_EXPANDED

Tags: php, date, iso8601

## Context

I want to produce an ISO-8601 string from a `DateTime` object in PHP 8.2. The `Date` class has [two related predefined constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetimeinterface.constants.types) for the `date_format()` function:

- `DATE_ISO8601` - `"Y-m-d\\TH:i:sO"`
  Note: This format is not compatible with ISO-8601, but is left this way for backward compatibility reasons. Use DateTimeInterface::ISO8601_EXPANDED, DateTimeInterface::ATOM for compatibility with ISO-8601 instead. (ref ISO8601:2004 section 4.3.3 clause d)
- `DATE_ISO8601_EXPANDED` - `"X-m-d\\TH:i:sP"`
  This format allows for year ranges outside of ISO-8601's normal range of 0000-9999 by always including a sign character. It also addresses that that timezone part (+01:00) is compatible with ISO-8601.

## Question

The `DATE_ISO8601_EXPANDED` format adds a leading `+` character to the string, which is NOT recognized by ISO8601 parsers in other languages (specifically Swift):

```
+2023-03-29T05:54:21+00:00
```

The output of `DATE_ISO8601` is:

```
2023-03-29T05:54:21+0000
```

I cannot determine what the warning about `DATE_ISO8601` means. Does it mean:

1. "This format doesn't adhere to the latest revision of ISO8601, so you should use the 'expanded' variant instead."

or

2. "There are bugs in this format that sometimes produce invalid ISO8601 output, so you should use the expanded format."

Hilariously, section 4 of ISO 8601 [is not publicly available without purchase](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:8601:-1:ed-1:v1:en), so I can't read it. But the "expanded" format doesn't appear to be standard ISO8601 either, since the spec calls for a leading `+` symbol only when the year is greater than 9999.

Comment: Just to clarify *I cannot determine what the warning about DATE_ISO8601 means.* - what is the warning you are talking about?

Comment: @nigelren The comment in the docs: "This format is not compatible with ISO-8601, but is left this way for backward compatibility reasons."

Comment: Interestingly `x` would be the optional `+`, while `X` always contains the `+`. If you wanted to be compatible with other parsers, using your own format string with `x` would probably do the trick. Of course, that's missing the point of using nicely predefined constants…

Comment: @deceze Yea, I don’t need to support years beyond 9999, so I originally thought I’d just use the first constant until I saw this warning in the docs and wasn’t sure if the older format string means I sometimes get non-spec-compliant output even WITH in-range years.

Comment: Here's the relevant ticket for this change: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80022

Comment: For what it's worth, I always use `'c'` or `DATE_ATOM`: https://3v4l.org/9kKch#v8.2.4 - It's a good question anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The note means that the format `DATE_ISO8601` is not at all compatible with ISO-8601 and you should not use it, instead use either `DATE_ISO8601_EXPANDED` or `DATE_ATOM`. The compatibility problem [is not related](https://externals.io/message/113657#114883) to whether or not you use a date with a year beyond 0000-9999. You can read more about that [here](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/whats-the-difference-between-php-datetime-atom-and-datetime-iso8601).

The `DATE_ISO8601_EXPANDED` format differs from `DATE_ATOM` only in the year representation, `DATE_ISO8601_EXPANDED` uses `'X'` instead of `'Y'`:

```
"Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP"
"X-m-d\\TH:i:sP"
```

So if you don't need expanded year representation for values outside 0-9999, use `DATE_ATOM`.

Expanded representation should be used only by prior agreement, this is probably why some parsers will not correctly handle the sign before the year. Although I'm also not sure if `DATE_ISO8601_EXPANDED` is compatible with ISO-8601, because it talks about a constant number of digits for expanded year representation.

You can find some links to ISO-8601 without paying here:
https://github.com/php/doc-en/pull/1619

Comment: The link to the discussion was very useful; thanks!